# Are these orders isomorphic?

Tags: order-theory

I wanted to ask if these orders are isomorphic - namely if my solutions are correct. Here $\leq$ means the standard order on integer or rational numbers and $\leq_\text{lex}$ means lexicographical defined with the help of standard order on axes.

- $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$ and $(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$ – I think these orders aren't isomorphic, because the set of rational numbers is dense and of integers not,
- $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z},\leq_\text{lex})$ and $(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$ – I think these orders are isomorphic (I do not know how to argue it formally),
- $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$ and $((0,\infty)\cap \mathbb{Q},\leq)$ – I think these orders aren't isomorphic, because the first set hasn't got the least element in the opposite to the second.

I would really appreciate checking the correctness of these solutions.

Comment: The first one is correct. For the second one, think about how many elements there can be between two elements of this order. For the third one, look again - neither order contains the least element. In fact, in 3 the sets will be isomorphic (hint: try to map elements of $(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$ to those of $(-\infty,1)\cap\mathbb Q$ using some rational function.

Comment: @saulspatz $\leq_{lex}$ is a linear order on $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ too.

Comment: As to the third, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) says, "Any dense countable totally ordered set with no highest and no lowest element can be mapped bijectively onto the rational numbers in an order-preserving way," so the answer would seem to be "yes," but I don't know the proof.

Comment: @Wojowu You're right, of course.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct.

In the second one the orders are not isomorphic. Note that in the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ there are infinitely many elements between $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$. Indeed, for each $n\geq 2$ we have $(1,1)<(1,n)<(2,1)$. On the other hand, in $\mathbb{Z}$ there are only finitely many elements between each two elements. Use this to show that there can't be an isomorphism here.

The third one: the orders are isomorphic by Cantor's theorem, which says that any two orders on countable sets which are linear, dense and have no first and last elements are isomorphic to each other.